# How to calculate fuel cost and mpg?

Tags: arithmetic

A car has a mileage of "5 miles per litre" and traveled a distance of 573 miles.  The cost of fuel is £1.09 per litre.  How do I compute the miles per gallon(mpg) and the total cost of fuel for the trip?
A formula or example would be great, so that I can refer to it, when I have this problem again.

Comment: Try to work it out yourself using cross multiplication.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication  Write 5 miles/per litre as 5 miles divided by one litre.  So if you travel 573 miles, and you go 5 miles on one litre, then you have to divide 573 by 5 to get the number of litres.

Comment: You would require $573/5=114.6$ litres. You should be able to calculate the cost now.

Comment: when multiplying  `114.6 litres` with `£1.09`, do i convert `£1.09` to `pence` and then divide the result by 100?

Comment: also is `114.6 litres` the mpg?

Comment: To compute the mpg you have to use the conversion from litres to gallons in the cross-multiplication.  Write the cross-multiplication on a sheet of paper.  It's not hard.  Also the units of measure can help you a great deal to work out what to multiply and divide.

Comment: honestly, this would make more sense if i had an example with the values?

Comment: @user892134 We've established you need $114.6$ litres of fuel at $109$ pence **per litre** so for every $1$ litre you pay $109$p. You need $114.6$ of these, so....

Answer (score 1):

You can find first Total fuel required which you can get by dividing 573 by 5. Then multiply the fuel which you found out in litres by cost per litre to get total cost